# Pass the value of a variable to a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to write a simple HTML file containing 10 buttons, each button with text from 0 to 9, and when a button is clicked it shows on the console the number corresponding to it.
The buttons have to be dynamically created in a javascript file.

Here is my code:

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  <!-- JQuery script -->
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="maindiv"></div> <!-- This div will contain the buttons. -->
</body>
```

Javascript *(test.js)* file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    DOM_ready();
});

function DOM_ready() {
    var maindiv = document.getElementById("maindiv");
    var button_create_aux;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        button_create_aux = document.createElement('button');
        button_create_aux.innerHTML = i; // sets the button text corresponding to its iteration value.

        $(button_create_aux).click(function () {
            clicked(i);
        });

        maindiv.appendChild(button_create_aux);
    }
}

function clicked(num) {
    console.log(num);
}
```

The problem is that when I click the buttons in the HTML page, it shows always on the console the last value given to the variable *i* used in the for loop (in this case, 10).

It looks like that in the line *clicked(i);* the argument passed is the reference to the variable *i*, not its value, so I want a way to pass the value that *i* has at each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I've closed this question as a duplicate which you should read, but the short answer is to change `for(var i=0;i<10;i++){` to `for(let i=0;i<10;i++){` to avoid a common closure.

Comment: In addition to the closure note, you could also use `bind()` to approach this issue.  `$(button_create_aux).click(clicked.bind(null, i));`

Comment: @EleazarEnrique Please use the Edit privilege responsibly. Use it to correct mistakes or improve the understanding of the question/code. Do not use it to alter code to your personal preference. There was nothing wrong with the original code formatting. Your edit just changes code from 2 space indents to 4 space indents.

Comment: @ScottMarcus sorry for that, I copied in my IDE and formatted it.  Thank you for advising me.